# ExpressionEngine updates not reflecting on site

Tags: expressionengine

A client has asked me to update their EE site. On the homepage, there is a small slider that shows text data. For each slide, the original creator of the site made entries and is displaying all of them in the slider as a channel called footerstats. The footer template references this channel.

I went to each entry, changed the info, saved. I then updated the footer template and channel just for the heck of it. I even cleared all caches. Still, the old info is still showing up on the homepage. Any tips? I am new to EE.

Comment: Any chance there is a 3rd party caching add-on in place like CE Cache? Maybe check your for that or similar caching add-ons.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that. Since I know who hosts the site, I am talking with them now. If no extra caching is involved, I am stumped.

Comment: Since caching is usually URL based a good way to test for cache is to load the same page with a different URL.  So if http://example.com is cached try http://example.com/index.php or http://example.com/your_template_group/index.php or whatever.

Comment: @user1729506 just letting you know about our proposal for an EE specific site here (if you already are supporting it, you need to link your account so your reputation counts towards it) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine

Comment: Is the page going to a "Submitted" page outlining the changes or does the page just seem to refresh? I'm here because my Entry page edits will not save but rather refresh on submit.

Answer (score 5):

Did you clear the cache folder directly instead of via EE? Sometimes I notice that with aggressive browser caching (Chrome) and sometimes just general clearing, it helps to actually manually delete the contents of the cache folder instead of just using the EE interface.

Comment: The db_cache folder is so large - I ended up just renaming mine with a date tagged on the end. EE recreated the folder for me and the changes finally appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the add-ons -> modules list to see if CE Cache or Template Morsels are installed. Those are the two third party caching add-ons that immediately come to mind that could directly lead to EE's "clear caches" not changing what you're seeing in the site, as they cache to the database.  You could also look for Stash - that also saves data outside of EE's native caching, but in a different manner than CE Cache or Template Morsels.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for CE Cache and clear any cache if it is installed.